# Set default python version

Tags: python, anaconda

After installing [Anaconda](https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/), when I run python sometimes I load the one provided with Anaconda, and others the one I installed with brew. Both versions are `2.7.6`, but I get a `Segmentation fault: 11` error, which is probably due to the fact that there are now two options. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Do you have the PYTHONPATH environment variable set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual fix for problems like this one is to make sure the version you want is first in the search path of your shell (or the other version isn't in the path - but that's sometimes impossible).

With Unix-like systems, check the value of the `$PATH` variable.

**[EDIT]** See [this document](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WrapperScript) for the general concept of [wrapper scripts](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WrapperScript).

Create such a script with this content:

```
#!/bin/sh
PATH="/Users/Alberto/anaconda/bi‌​n:$PATH"
export PATH
exec anaconda
```

This assumes that the Python which you want to use is in the folder `/Users/Alberto/anaconda/bi‌​n` and that the program which you want to wrap is called `anaconda`.

Make this script executable. After that, you can start the application using the wrapper script and it should always work.

Note: [Platypus](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/12046/platypus) might make it easier to use the script.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I get from `$ PATH`: `-bash: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/Users/Alberto/anaconda/bin:/Users/Alberto/anaconda/bin://anaconda/bin://anaconda/bin:/Users/Alberto/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Applications/Sublime: No such file or directory`

Comment: Use `echo $PATH` to see the current value. As you can see, the version from `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework` comes first. Depending on what you want to break, `.bash_profile` is probably the wrong place. For errors like that, I create a new script that fixes PATH and then starts Anaconda. From then on, you can always use the script to start the application without breaking anything else.

Comment: If you change PATH in a global place, then everyone will start using the Anaconda version of Python which might break other stuff.

Comment: OK. What do I have to do to fix things as you suggested?